# sonar-maven-plugin 3.3.0.603 changelog

Tags: documentation, sonarqube, maven-plugin, sonar-maven-plugin

Is these any change to find changelog/release note for 3.3.0.60
34?

https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-maven has just a broken link to http://sonarsource.github.io/sonar-maven

Comment: This is a good, objective question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the release notes:
https://jira.sonarsource.com/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10977&version=13419

The ".0.603" part doesn't appear in the version number because "603" is the build number.

Comment: Is this official version policy now? 3.2 was without build number.

Comment: Yes. All new artifact names should include build numbers